# How to crawl a Kinesis Firehose output folder from S3 to Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to read my dynamo db stream data into S3 . Here is the flow :

```
DynamoDb -> DynamoDb Streams -> Kinesis Streams -> Kinesis Firehose -> S3 -> Glue Crawler -> Athena
```

This is working fine but the problem is that Kinesis firehose creates new folder every hour and that means I have to wait until the next run of crawler. How do I get data in Athena in real time?

Thanks

Comment: You can setup streaming Glue Job for real time data processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can cut out the Kinesis Firehose part from the pipeline and directly write from Kinesis Streams to S3. This should enable you to have realtime data. Another way would be to remove partitioning on a hourly basis, I assume you have that in place, since you need to crawl every hour.

Comment: How can I remove hourly partitioning ? Kinesis Firehose is needed to convert data in parquet format.

Comment: In the configuration of your Firehose.